# '.pbxproj' file is missing in commits list

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, git, pbxproj

currently building a project clone and push all the changes to my github account step by step. 
And i always used to see 'Twitter.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj' checked together with modified .swift files. 
However, i don't see it now. I've reopened and did some additional changes to the code, but still nothing.
Is that ok, if it's not pushed? 
And how do i get it back to normal if it's not?

[image: Xcode screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list you are looking at is generated by `git status`. Well, `git status` does not include any files that *didn't change*. So you should not expect to see *project.pbxproj* in the list unless you did something that would change it (like making a new code file and adding it to your project). Merely editing your existing code wouldn't change it, so it doesn't appear.

(In a way, this is a case of the classic confusion as to what `git status` means. Beginners often think that it's a list of your files, or a list of the files that will go into this commit. It isn't. A commit always contains *all your files*. But git doesn't bother to list them in the `git status`, because that could be an unnecessarily huge list. There are ways to find out what's in the commit, but the screen you are displaying is not how to do it.)

**TL;DR** Don't worry, be happy.